# Beginner EmacsLisp: Swap Left and Right expressions of an equation

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am new to EmacsLisp. I have been using emacs for the last 18 months, but never made any customizations of my own. In order to learn to do that however, I am trying to solve the following problem:
Given a line of characters that form an equation of the form
(some characters A)=(some characters B),
I want to swap the two expressions A and B.

I identified the function that seems to be tailor-made for this- [`transpose-regions start1 end1 start2 end2 &optional leave-markers`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Transposition.html#Transposition).
I have the following questions-

1. How do I specify `start1 end1` with a regular expression? It seems that positions are counted from the beginning of the buffer!
2. What if I want to solve a more generalized problem where I keep the cursor/marker over the central `=` and want to do the swap? How do I specify the `start end` values there?

This  is a learning exercise for me. Please do not post complete solutions. I will put that in as an edit for people who end up here looking for a solution. Any advice regarding coding style in emacs lisp would be appreciated!

Comment: Check out the functions `(point)`, `(re-search-forward)`, `(re-search-backward)`, `(match-beginning)`, `(match-end)`, `(beginning-of-line)`, and `(end-of-line)`.

Comment: @Thomas your comment was as useful as the answer I marked correct, and you posted earlier! If you would reconsider posting, this as an answer I would mark yours correct.

Comment: No worries, as long as you've got your answer, I'm happy :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want a complete solution, I'll just give you a list
of functions that achieve it:
`transpose-regions`, `point`, `line-beginning-position`, `line-end-position`.

That is all you need assuming that you've navigated to = by hand.
`move-beginning-of-line` and `re-search-forward` if you want to navigate to = in code.